# flutter TextField not be updated

Tags: flutter, textfield

I have created an app using flutter. The app works fairly well but one big functionality does not work. When I retrieve data from the Firestore database and display the records in a listview I want to click on any of the records and go to a screen where I can edit the record. Clicking on the record and navigating to the edit page works fine however, the data does not get populated in the TextField. When I debug the app the data is there but the TextFields never get populated with the data. Below is some of my code.

This is the edit page
'''

```
  // existing record: Put data from database into the TextFields
  // Updates Controllers
  clientFNameController.text = widget.trxns.clientFName;

  // Updates State
  new Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
    final trxnProvider = Provider.of<TrxnProvider>(context, listen: false);
    trxnProvider.loadValues(widget.trxns);
  });


super.initState();

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final trxnProvider = Provider.of<TrxnProvider>(context);
  final trxns = Provider.of<List<Trxns>>(context);


TextField(
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            onChanged: (value) {
              trxnProvider.changeclientLName(value, loggedInUid);
            },
            decoration:
                kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(hintText: 'Client Last Name'),
          ),
```

'''

This is the Provider class
'''

```
class TrxnProvider with ChangeNotifier {
   final firestoreService = FirestoreService();
   String _clientLName;

   String get clientLName => _clientLName;

loadValues(Trxns trxns) {
  _clientLName = trxns.clientLName;
}
```

'''

Comment: Maybe you forget to assign ```clientFNameController``` to the ```TextField``` ?

Comment: Why is there a super.initState outside of initState?

Comment: I am sorry for not putting all the details in my post. super.initstate is inside initState. This code in in the initState as well: clientLNameController.text = widget.trxns.clientLName;

Answer (score 0):

On the part you instance the controller put the initial data there:

```
final clientFNameController = TextEditingController(text: widget.trxns.clientFName);
```

In the other hand I really recommend you if you are managing state with Provider, try to not use StafulWidget and to have the controller on the TrxnProvider class.

Comment: Thank you for your response. So, I can simply from StatefulWidget to StatelessWidget? What do you mean by "to have the controller on the TrxnProvider class" ? I am new to all of this.

Comment: Yes if you apply the class TrxnProvider is because it is going to MANAGE any mutable variable, so on the main cases you are not going to need Stateful anymore.
So when you *notifyListeners* the ui is going to get rebuilded wherever a listener of that instance exists...